# Problems while filtering pandas dataframe by row values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    Col
0   []
1   []
2   [(foo, bar), (foo, bar)]
3   []
4   []
5   []
6   []
7   [(foo, bar), (foo, bar)]
```

I would like to remove all the empty lists (*):

```
    Col
2   [(foo, bar), (foo, bar)]
7   [(foo, bar), (foo, bar)]
```

For the above I tried:

```
df = df.loc[df.Col != '[]']
df
```

and

```
df.pipe(lambda d: d[d['Col'] != '[]'])
```

However, none of them worked. So, my question is how can I remove all the empty lists from the dataframe like (*)?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing through the data frame as though the values were [strings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) instead of lists may work:

```
df[df.astype(str)['Col'] != '[]']
```

Comment: `df.Col.str.`, I also tried that one before posting this question.

Comment: @tumbleweed You have to use `astype` to declare the series as a `str` in this case. `.str` implies you're planning to manipulate the variable after the assignment, or more simply, do something with it. It's pretty much there as an indicator for the preceding function to work with. e.g. `str.replace()` wouldn't work correctly if used without the column having already been made up of `str` values or having not been declared upon using `astype`.

Comment: @tumbleweed If this helps, from the doc itself - `Series.astype`: Cast object to input numpy.dtype Return a copy when copy = True

Comment: @tumbleweed So relating back to `df.Col.str`- `dtype`, being the `str`, hasn't been 'casted' :) Hope this helps. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the lists with `.str` accessor:

```
df[df.Col.str.len() != 0]

#                        Col
#3  [(foo, bar), (foo, bar)]
#6  [(foo, bar), (foo, bar)]
```